# How to name multiple result set returned from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that returns several "result sets" at a time.
By default it names these reult set as `"Table","Table1"`

But I'd like to know if there is some way I can set the desired  names of each result set within the text of the stored procedure.

Comment: Short answer: no. To SQL Server, it's just a bunch of result sets which don't have names or anything associated with them. SQL Server doesn't have a notion of "naming" result sets.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way you could assign names to the result sets.